# Knockout rendered link, click handler issue

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

Lets talk with code:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" title="Shows player rankings">                
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-bind="foreach: userRanks">
                <!-- ko if: ($index() === 0) -->
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" title="Refresh ranks"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { title: $data.rank}">
                        <!-- ko text: $data.username --><!-- /ko -->
                        <span class="badge" data-bind="text: $data.score"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- ko if: ($index() === ($parent.userRanks().length - 1)) -->
                <li class="pull-right">                        
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnPush" class="btn btn-default" data-url="@Url.Action("PushPlayerinfo", "Home")">Update score</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right" data-bind="attr: {title: $parent.currentUserName}">
                    <a href="#">You <span class="badge" data-bind="text: $parent.currentUsertotalScore"></span> / <span data-bind="text: $parent.currentUserRank"></span></a>
                </li>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
</div>
```

I have registered click handler to link 'btnPush' as:

```
$("#btnPush").on('click', function () {
//My code
});
```

Just using knockout foreach control, virtual elements and contexts, don't know what i am missing but click **never get registered** for this link this way. Inline Html `onClick()` works though:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="pushData(this);" id="btnPush" class="btn btn-default" title="Click to persist current score" data-url="@Url.Action("PushPlayerinfo", "Home")">Update score</a>
```

Also, if same link is outside of ul-container (Outside of foreach binding), it works fine. Can someone suggest me please?

Comment: Because your elements are generate dynamically, You should use delegated events, well documented in jquery doc.

Comment: If you are anyway using knockout why don't you use it to also handle the click event for you?

Comment: @nemesv Good comment. I will even go as far as to say that it could be an answer, if not for the OP then for folks that end up on this question with a search query. When using KO the [`click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) is meant for exactly this task.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is if you are accessing DOM elements in a KO view with $(''), chances are you need a custom binding. However, with this example given, you can just code the click method in your viewmodel as knockout.js provides you out of the box with a click event binding. Try and avoid doing any sort of direct DOM manipulation within your viewmodel, whether it be jQuery or any other sort of javascript framework. One of the main points of MVVM is to have your viewmodel completely decoupled from your view, and that is what custom bindings can help provide for you.

Comment: Unrelated sidenote, but using $index() to insert items at the beginning and the end of the list is a bit ugly.  You can use `<!-- ko foreach: userRanks -->` to avoid having to do that.

Comment: @pglynn: now, i am using no DOM references but $.ajax to update viewmodel fields and no DOM references.

Comment: @Retsam: You are right but in my case both first and last li's need special handling using $parent context.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the click event with knockout. It is a bad practice use jQuery to handle the DOM when you use knockout and also it will easy if you use the ko click binding.

Check the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

*If you need run a method inside a ko foreach, and this method belongs to the VM remember to use the $parent or $root key.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>                        
    <a data-bind="click: $parent.yourMethod()>link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```